# Redux, action type not dispatched

Tags: redux

I am creating a reducer in `Redux` with the following function:

```
export const createSingleObjectReducer = (updateActionType, initialState = {}, debug = false) => {
  const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    if (!action) {
      return state
    }   

    switch (action.type) {
      case updateActionType: {
        if (action.updates === undefined) {
          console.error(`Invalid ${updateActionType} action: action.updates is undefined: `, action)
          return state
        }   

        const newState = { ...state, ...action.updates }
        if (debug) {
          console.log('singleObjectReducer: applying action: ', action, 'State changing from ', state, ' to ', newState)
        }   
        return newState
      }   
      default:
        return state
    }   
  }

  return reducer
}
```

Like that:

```
export const RECEIVE_VARIANT_TAGTYPES_DATA = 'RECEIVE_VARIANT_TAGTYPES_DATA'

const rootReducer = combineReducers(Object.assign({
  ...
  ...
    variantTagTypesData: createSingleObjectReducer(RECEIVE_VARIANT_TAGTYPES_DATA, {
    variantTagTypes: {},
    variantFunctionalTagTypes: {},
  }),
  ...
}))
```

And then dispatching the action in another file like that:

```
dispatch({ type: RECEIVE_VARIANT_TAGTYPES_DATA,
  updates: {
    variantTagTypes: responseJson.variantTagTypes,
    variantFunctionalTagTypes: responseJson.variantFunctionalTagTypes,
  },  
})
```

The action is not dispatched for an unknown reason. What are possible reasons for that?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I was dispatching several actions before the `RECEIVE_VARIANT_TAGTYPES_DATA` and what was happening is: previous actions get dispatched, then updates happen, selectors called, some components start rendering which causes the crash because the `RECEIVE_VARIANT_TAGTYPES_DATA` has not yet been dispatched and relevant data updated. It would be nice if we could have some wrapper around several `dispatch` - statement to guarantee that first state should be changed according to all of them and only then other stuff can happen.